# Socialite Driver [VKontakte] not supported

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

I'm having an issue when trying to use the Socialite Manager driver for VKontakte Auth. This is the error I'm faced with:

> Driver [VKontakte] not supported.

i used https://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/v-kontakte.html
this guide

My app.php:

```
\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class, // add
```

My EventServiceProvider:

```
protected $listen = [
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // add your listeners (aka providers) here
        'SocialiteProviders\\VKontakte\\VKontakteExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
];
```

Controller:

```
return Socialite::with('VKontakte')->redirect();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar trouble, changing driver name in controller to the "vkontakte" in lower case helped me.

```
return Socialite::with('vkontakte')->redirect();
```